# Perforce Merge Graph Depot to normal Depot

Tags: git, perforce

I have setup perforce server with graph depot, to which I mirror some repo from Github.

Is it possible to automatically (or at least manually), merge this mirrored repo to normal p4 depot ?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible due to the fact that graph depots are basically Git repos rather than Perforce depots.  Maybe some interesting work has been done over the last couple of years that I don't know about though, so I'll watch with interest to see if anyone has a different answer.  :)